# What is the correct way to express equality of distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

For instance, is it correct to write

$$ \mathcal{N}(0, n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \,? $$

Or is an equals sign not the proper convention?

Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @Muselive That seems to address how to express that two random variables have the same distribution, but not equivalence of distributions themselves.

Comment: what do you mean by "=", equal in distribution?